# Calculating second largest number in array (Javascript) : Seems to work in Sandbox but fails Hackerrank testing

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Tried to determine the second largest number in an array (Javascript) on CodeSandbox. It seems to work fine, but it fails the CodeWars testing. I have added a dummy array just to run my own tests in Sandbox.(Have mercy, I'm a beginner and this is my first StackOverFlow question)

```
const nums = [3, 100.3, 88, 1, -2.4, 9, 18];

const getSecondLargest = (nums) => {
  const descending = nums.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  return descending[1];
};

console.log(getSecondLargest(nums));  // console returns 88
```

EDIT: Okay so I with my super-tired brain I said CodeWars, when I actually meant Hackerrank (so sorry!). I realized they didn't necessarily test with NaNs, but they did have repeating numbers, so using the index of [1] isn't ideal. The exercise is from the 10 Days of Javascript - Day 3: Arrays https://hackerrank.com/domains/tutorials/10-days-of-javascript

So I now tried this code below, and it passes...but my code seems a bit janky, is there a cleaner way to write this, and can I combine it with the isNan logic then?

```
const nums = [3, 100, 88, 100, -2.4, 9, 18];

const getSecondLargest = (nums) => {
  const ascending = nums.sort((a, b) => a - b);


  if (ascending[ascending.length - 2] === ascending[ascending.length - 1]) {
    return ascending[ascending.length - 3];
  } else {
    return ascending[ascending.length - 2];
  }
};

console.log(getSecondLargest(nums));  // console returns 88
```

Comment: Does the CodeWars task specify what to do when `descending[1]` doesn’t exist or the array contains non-numbers? Does it specify if the array should be mutated? Is there a constraint that the algorithm should run in linear time?

Comment: You mentioned in failed in the CodeWars testing. What was the error message you received?

Comment: Can you quote the original code challenge?

Comment: If [this (from Google search)](https://www.codewars.com/kata/578fe7e2149935740f000525) is the problem page, then you are not handling non-numbers.

Comment: In that case, you can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the non-numbers: `const descending = nums.filter(n => !isNaN(n)).sort((a, b) => b - a);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there maybe strings in the array and you need to handle that. Here are a few ways:

One is to filter the non-numerical stuff out before sorting. You can use `isNaN()` to test if an object "is not a number".

```
const getSecondLargest = (nums) => {
  const descending = nums
                     .filter(n => !isNaN(n))
                     .sort((a, b) => b - a);
  return descending.length < 2 ? undefined : descending[1];
};
```

Another option is to handle the strings in sorting. Push them to the end of the array:

```
const getSecondLargest = (nums) => {
  const descending = nums.sort((a, b) => {
                        if (isNaN(a) && isNaN(b)) return 0;
                        if (isNaN(a)) return 1;
                        if (isNaN(b)) return -1;
                        return b - a;
                     });
  return descending.length < 2 || isNaN(descending[1]) ? undefined : descending[1];
};
```

A third way is a simple `for` loop that keeps track of the 2 highest values:

```
const getSecondLargest = (nums) => {
    let max1 = undefined;
    let max2 = undefined; 
    for (let n of nums) {
        if (isNaN(n)) continue;
        if (max2 === undefined || n > max2) {
            if (max1 === undefined || n > max1 ) {
                max2 = max1;
                max1 = n;
            }
            else {
                max2 = n;
            }
        }
    }
    return max2;
}
```